# Putting a span inside a span inline

Tags: html, css

I want to display a large span with a large font size and within that inline, I want to add subtitles that are divided into two rows (Title | One) (Title | Two) etc..

I can achieve this somewhat by using manual margining and absolute positioning of the subtitles, but the HTML and CSS gets very messy very quickly. Perhaps I should use CSS grid?

I have attached the html body structure I hope to be using and  `.content` css that I will be using. And the image of what I hope to achieve.

[image]

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    <span class="name">Firstname Las</span>
    <span class="title">Title 1</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>            
  </h1>
</div>

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Is the image is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes

Comment: so... why haven't you tried out css grid?

Comment: @A.Lau Because it's overkill and not necessary here?

Comment: @torazaburo well the accepted answer is hacky and relies on fixing the length, which means that it is unlikely to be transferrable to future uses. A grid or flexbox will give better functionality overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below solution :

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.fname{
  display:block
}
.title{      
  font-size: 11px;
    width: 20px !important;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    <span class="fname">Firstname</span>
    <span class="lname">Las</span>
    <span class="title">Title one</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>            
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `display: inline-block`.

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size: 72px; text-transform: uppercase; ">
  First Name<br/>Las
  <span class="inline">Title One</span>
  <span class="inline">Title Two</span>
  <span>
</span>
```

Comment: Is it possible that instead of Title One on same line, they be on different lines?

`Title  Title
One  Two`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 300px;
    word-break: break-word;
  }

  span.title {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 42px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    <span class="name">Firstname Las</span>
    <span class="title">Title 1</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>            
  </h1>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2133/